# How to fade a CCLayerColor and it's children to a given opacity? Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opacity, cclayer

I am trying to figure out how to fade the layer and its children to a given opacity. This is what I am doing.

```
    - (id)init
    {

        if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 255, 255)] )) {

            CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"LevelsBackGround.png"];
            background.position = ccp([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * .5f ,160);
            [self addChild:background];

            CCSprite *text = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"SwipeText.png"];
            text.position = ccp([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height *.5, 17);
            [self addChild:text];


            sceneText = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Yard" fontName:@"Baskerville-Bold" fontSize:20];
            sceneText.position = ccp([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height *.5, 300);
            sceneText.color = ccc3(172, 169, 164);
            [self addChild:sceneText];

        [self performSelector:@selector(LaunchLevel:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.f];

}
    - (void ) LaunchLevel: (id) sender {

        [self runAction:[CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:.5 opacity:127]];
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything. If I remove the background sprite in order to see the blue color that I have the layer set to and then build it, then the blue background gets faded exactly as it should. So my question is, why is it not working to fade out all of the layers children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opacity property does not get propagated to the children. If you want , you can override the setOpacity method :

```
// in your .h file, an iVar 

GLubyte _opacity;

// in you .m, the overrides

- (void)setOpacity:(GLubyte)opacity {

    for (id child in self.children) {
        id <CCRGBAProtocol> opaqueChild = (id <CCRGBAProtocol>) child;
        if ([opaqueChild respondsToSelector:@selector(setOpacity:)]) {
            opaqueChild.opacity = opacity;
        } else {
            // you must decide here what to do for your own situation
            // and the children you are likely to have in there
        }
    }
    _opacity = opacity;
}

- (GLubyte)opacity {
    return _opacity;
}
```

edit : extending a CCLayerColor (this compiles, have not actually tested it, but should work). Just add this in your .m file (the implementation for your class) :

```
- (void)setOpacity:(GLubyte)opacity {

    for (id child in self.children) {
        id <CCRGBAProtocol> opaqueChild = (id <CCRGBAProtocol>) child;
        if ([opaqueChild respondsToSelector:@selector(setOpacity:)]) {
            opaqueChild.opacity = opacity;
        } else {
            // you must decide here what to do for your own situation
            // and the children you are likely to have in there
        }
    }
    [super setOpacity:opacity];
}
```

Comment: I guess I was misinformed, I was told on the cocos2d forum that an action would be applied to all the layers children.

Comment: I'm looking at cocos version 2 above, opacity is not propagated. I assume this is one of your own classes, that extends CCNode somehow. Just add an iVar and add the code in your .m file (the implementation of the class). The code above was for a CCNode derivative. Does your class extend CCColorLayer ?

Comment: Yes my class is a subclass of CCLayerColor.

Comment: So add these two methods to your CCLayerColor subclass. And you will be able not only to change opacity of it's children, but, for example, use opacity actions (CCFadeIn, CCFadeOut, CCFadeTo) on it. Just one improvement - create array of opaque children and add all you want to react to setOpacity: method of your layer. In this case you will be able to fade not only children, but children of the children.

Answer (score 4):

As of Cocos2d-x v3-ish (I'm using v3.4); If you're adding several `Sprite`s to a `Layer` you can now set a flag on the layer to indicate that opacity should be cascaded down to its respective children with the following command:

```
local layer = cc.Layer:create()
layer:addChild(cc.Sprite("hero-dude.png"))
layer:setCascadeOpacityEnabled(true)
layer:runAction(cc.FadeTo:create(0.5, 127))
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting recursively the opacity of the children does not render very well ("opacity overlapping" effect).

If you want to fade a whole hierarchy of nodes "as a whole", you can use `CCRenderTexture` (to render your node graph and fade it as a single image).

And if your children are somehow animated you need to update your `CCRenderTexture` frequently (quite CPU-costly).

More details here: http://2sa-studio.blogspot.com/2013/01/fading-node-hierarchy-with.html

Comment: Finally got a use for this. +1